# If $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, show that $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)-2}$ is bounded and Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

If $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, show that $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)-2}$ is bounded and Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I can say that $g(x):[0,1]\to [-2,-1]$. How to show the boundedness and integrability of $g(x)$ without using continuity or monotonic property of functions? Please help me.

Comment: no I cannot. need help

Comment: what is your definition of riemann integrability? Surely you can at least show it is bounded... Can you tell what condition is needed for boundedness?

Comment: for boundedness I have to show that $|g(x)|\leq K$ for some positive integer $K$. I see that $f(x)-2\neq 0$ for $x\in [0,1]$, but don't know how to write all.

Comment: yes that is the definition of boundedness, but what hypothesis in the problem do you think makes this true?

Comment: f is integrable means f is bounded.

Comment: riemann integrability condition: $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$

Comment: Use the theorem : *if $f$ is Riemann integrable and bounded away from zero then $1/f$ is Riemann integrable*. In your question $f(x) - 2$ is bounded away from $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable, then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P=\{0=x_{0}<\cdots<x_{n}=1\}$ on $[0,1]$ such that 
\begin{align*}
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(M_{i}-m_{i})\Delta x_{i}<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
where $\Delta x_{i}=(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$, $M_{i}=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}f(x)$, $m_{i}=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}f(x)$.

Note that $M_{i}-2<0$ and it is not hard to see that for all $x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{M_{i}-2}\leq\dfrac{1}{f(x)-2}\leq\dfrac{1}{m_{i}-2},
\end{align*}
so with $\widetilde{M}_{i}=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}g(x)$, $\widetilde{m}_{i}=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}g(x)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{M}_{i}-\widetilde{m}_{i}\leq\dfrac{1}{m_{i}-2}-\dfrac{1}{M_{i}-2}.
\end{align*}
And we have $-2\leq M_{i}-2,m_{i}-2\leq -1$, so 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{(M_{i}-2)(m_{i}-2)}\leq 1,
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
U(g,P)-L(g,P)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\widetilde{M}_{i}-\widetilde{m}_{i})\Delta x_{i}\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{M_{i}-m_{i}}{(M_{i}-2)(m_{i}-2)}\Delta x_{i}\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}(M_{i}-m_{i})\Delta x_{i}\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: Please elaborate the step: $-2\leq M_{i}-2,m_{i}-2\leq -1$ implies $\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{(M_{i}-2)(m_{i}-2)}\leq 1,
\end{align*}$. Here $-2\leq M_{i}-2$ implies $\frac{1}{M_i-2}\leq -\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{m_i-2}\geq -1$

Comment: Also $U(g,P)-U(g,P)$ would be $U(g,P)-L(g,P)$. and all $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}$ would be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$, I think. Please check.

Comment: With $-2\leq M_{i}-2\leq -1$, then $1\leq-(M_{i}-2)\leq 2$, so $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq-\dfrac{1}{M_{i}-2}\leq 1$, so is $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq-\dfrac{1}{m_{i}-2}\leq 1$, so $\left(-\dfrac{1}{M_{i}-2}\right)\left(-\dfrac{1}{m_{i}-2}\right)\leq 1$, so the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is bounded because if $f(x)\in[0,1]$ then $g(x)\in \left[-1,\dfrac{-1}{2}\right]$. Recall that $f$ is integrable if and only if $\Lambda(f)$ (the set where $f$ is discontinuous) have measure zero. Note that $g(x)=h\circ f$ where $h(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-2}$. Recall that $h\circ f$ is continuous if $h$ and $f$ are both continuous. Clearly $h$ is continuous, thus, $h\circ f$ is discontinuous iff $f$ is discontinuous. We conclude that $\Lambda(f)=\Lambda(h\circ f)$ and therefore, $g$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ we have $ 2-f(x) \in [1,2]$ therefore $\frac 
 {1}{2-f(x)} \in [1/2,1]$

Thus $g(x) = \frac {1}{2-f(x)} $ is  bounded.

Note that the discontinuities of g(x) are the same as discontinuities as f(x), hence g(x) is also Riemann integrable.

Comment: Can it be proved by $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$.

Comment: @rama_ran Yes, of course, but it is very messy. I am using a theorem due to Cauchy, that a bounded function is in Riemann integrable if the set of discontinuities is countable.